# How to add spaces while renaming files in batch

Tags: batch-file, rename

So recently, I have tried to make myself a batch script to rename files by replacing a certain string by another. It is sucessful, until you add spaces. This is what my code currently looks like :

```
@echo off
:0
cls
set /p "str=String to replace   : "
set /p "rsw=Replace string with : "
set /p "infile=In file : "
for %%a in ("%infile%") do (
cd %%~dpa
set "fn1=%%~nxa"
call set fn2=%%fn1:%str%=%rsw%%%
ren "%%~dpa%fn1%" "%%~dpa%fn2%"
)
echo "%str%" "%rsw%"
echo "%fn1%" "%fn2%"
pause
goto 0
```

**Solved :**

I have modified my code to look like this and now it works :

```
@echo off
set /p "str=String to replace   : "
set /p "rsw=Replace string with : "
title Replace "%str%" with "%rsw%"
:0
cls
set /p "infile=In file : "
for %%a in ("%infile%") do (
set "wkdir=%%~dpa"
set "fn1=%%~nxa"
)
call set "fn2=%%fn1:%str%=%rsw%%%"
cd %wkdir%
ren "%fn1%" "%fn2%"
pause
goto 0
```

I even tried using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` but it didn't help so I simply took the renaming process out of the `for` command.

The only problem that I now run into is renaming a file containing spaces in it's name.

Comment: Works for me replacing spaces in name...

Answer (score 2):

First issue: We normally assume that a batch is being run from the prompt. You appear to be using the "point, click and giggle" method (clicking a "shortcut")

Initially, a `cmd` instance contains no user-set variables. It is standard practice to include

```
setlocal
```

immediately after the `@echo off` line to establish a "local" environment. Changes made to that local environment (like establishing `str` etc) are removed when the batch ends.

Since you have not used this `setlocal` statement, any variables you have established in a run remain set for subsequent runs (if you are running from the prompt).

Next issue : the ever-faithful "delayed expansion" characteristic (see Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947
).

You would understand from there that in your code, `ren "%%~dpa%fn1%" "%%~dpa%fn2%"` will be resolved using the values of `fn1` and `fn2` as they stood when the `for` was parsed, not the modified values that were `set` within the `for` block.

It could be that you are being deceived by the fact that `fn1` and `fn2` would retain their values when the loop back to `:0` is executed, or even between invocations if you are running from the prompt where the modified values are not deleted in consequence of the absence of a `setlocal`.

Third issue: a `ren` statement *may* have a path specifier on its first argument, but **must NOT** have a path specifier on the second - only a name[.extension] is allowed.